# input[type="radio"]#amountSelectionOther:checked+label+input#amountSelectionOtherField{display: inline-block;} not working in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-selectors

Working with a set of radio select buttons and a text input field in HTML.

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="amount_choose" id="amountSelection40" value="40.00">
    <label for="amountSelection40">$40.00</label>

    <input type="radio" name="amount_choose" id="amountSelectionOther" value="Other">
    <label for="amountSelectionOther" class="amountSelectionLabelOther">Other</label>
    <input type="text" id="amountSelectionOtherField" name="amount_Other">
</fieldset>
```

I have CSS marking the text input#amountSelectionOtherField as display none.  The idea being I only want the text box to show up if the "Other" radio button is checked.

```
input[type="radio"]#amountSelectionOther:checked+label+input#amountSelectionOtherField
    {display: inline-block;}
```

The CSS works in Chrome, Firefox, IE on a Windows machine and Chrome, Firefox on my MAC but not on Safari.

Interestingly enough when I view the page in Safari on my iOS devices it doesn't appear to work either, however if after I have selected the "other" radio button and then do an oration change on my device the text input will appear.  If I change the radio selector back to 40, the text input does not disappear until I change my orientation again.

I am NOT using ANY media queries in my CSS file at all.  So is this just a quirk of Safari?  Any suggestion about how to make this work without having to resort to JS?

Comment: This is a known issue in Safari. It's nice to see that it hasn't been fixed at all in the past several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the following in Safari (ver 8.0.2) and it worked fine. I simplified the selection by using a general sibling (~) selector.

```
input#amountSelectionOtherField{display: none;}
input#amountSelectionOther:checked ~ input#amountSelectionOtherField {display: inline-block; }
```

Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/ugnyaLua/14/

Here is an article on the ~ selector: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/g/general-sibling/